# Keeping a hard coded rereference of Class Objects names to use in a PHP Registry

Tags: php, registry

I'm wondering whether this is a good or a bad practice and what may be a better solution for this case. Basically, I have a PHP Registry that can instantiate or return the existing instance of a Class Object by stating:

```
$classObject = $this->registry->getClassInstance(ObjectPath);
```

ObjectPath is a namespace in this case, because that is how my project is set up. So a fully working example would be:

```
$mysqli = $this->registry->getClassInstance('\application\models\Database\drivers\MySQLi');
```

However, instead of manually typing the class namespace everytime, I have instead:

```
$mysqli = $this->registry->getClassInstance($this->registry->mySQLiDriver());
```

which returns the namespace, making easier to use and update the project. Is this a bad idea though? Are there better practices known for achieving the same result already?

Answer (score 0):

It think you should use composer to do this automatically for you. It is a great tool: https://getcomposer.org/ 
It automatically figures out what to instantiate based on namespace you provide. 
However if you really want to do this by yourself I would not recommend you to use absolute paths from your application root.